# Installing Ganache GUI in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, programming, npm, javascript, ethereum

How [exactly](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/71369/70773) is Ganache [installed](https://superuser.com/q/1505768/977796) on Ubuntu?

The [approach](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/73922/70773) of using `git` looks advantageous, yet, I'd expect a sort of wrapper around git for use from within `npm` or similar.

Or does this have to be manually downloaded?

The console version is [easily](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/blob/master/README.md) enough installed with:

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

yet I'm seeing no such option for the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/

just go to this page it should find out your OS version. If it's unable to find than you can go to the github repo of the Ganache GUI : https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases -> Check the assets section of the release to find the right OS.